# add a running index to pandas partitioned by user id

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Given this dataset

```
CUSTOMER_ID,ORDER_AT
A,2020-11-11 23:30:13
A,2020-11-11 23:32:53
A,2020-11-11 23:34:44
A,2020-11-11 23:35:55
B,2020-11-11 23:37:54
B,2020-11-11 23:39:23
C,2020-11-09 23:59:46
C,2020-11-10 0:03:04
C,2020-11-10 0:05:35
C,2020-11-10 0:19:40
C,2020-11-11 2:48:17
C,2020-11-11 2:49:06
C,2020-11-11 2:50:39
C,2020-11-11 2:51:57
D,2020-11-14 1:12:52
D,2020-11-14 1:13:14
D,2020-11-14 16:56:18
```

how would I create a running secondary index of transaction id partitioned by the CUSTOMER_ID?

my desired output would be

```
CUSTOMER_ID,CUSTOMER_TRANSACTION_ID,ORDER_AT
A,0,2020-11-11 23:30:13
A,1,2020-11-11 23:32:53
A,2,2020-11-11 23:34:44
A,3,2020-11-11 23:35:55
B,0,2020-11-11 23:37:54
B,1,2020-11-11 23:39:23
C,0,2020-11-09 23:59:46
C,1,2020-11-10 0:03:04
C,2,2020-11-10 0:05:35
C,3,2020-11-10 0:19:40
C,4,2020-11-11 2:48:17
C,5,2020-11-11 2:49:06
C,6,2020-11-11 2:50:39
C,7,2020-11-11 2:51:57
D,0,2020-11-14 1:12:52
D,1,2020-11-14 1:13:14
D,2,2020-11-14 16:56:18
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `Groupby`   and `cumcount()`.

```
df['CUSTOMER_TRANSACTION_ID']=df.groupby('CUSTOMER_ID').cumcount()
```

Comment: I"m not sure you need the cumsum. the cumcount is sufficient (based on OP's output)

Comment: You are right @sammywemmy, will edit. Thanks

Comment: perfect, thanks! yeah the cumcount is enough